# SharedPreferences makes app force close

Tags: android, crash, sharedpreferences, forceclose

I want to read and write `SharedPreferences` through a class, but when I call this class in my Activity it makes the app crash/force close

If the `CheckBox` "Remember email" is checked the app will remember the email.

my `LoginActivity`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);        
        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(); // this makes the app crash
        String email = appPreferences.getPreferenceString("email");
        // ...
```

the class `appPreferences`

```
public class AppPreferences extends Activity
{
    private SharedPreferences settings = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = this.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_CREDENTIALS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public String getPreferenceString(String key) {
        return settings.getString(key, DEFAULT_STRING);
    }
    public void setPreferenceString(String key, String value) {
    editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    }
// ...
```

I've been looking for some hours to fix this and I tried several solutions from SO. I do call the `getSharedPreferences` method in the `onCreate` method so that wouldn't be the problem.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Java and Android developing so please describe fully with examples. Other solutions with a complete different approach are welcome too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your LogCat. What kind of errors do you have?

Comment: @Dediqated Have you tried my solution.. and still error post the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are trying to create an object of class which extending Activity class. if AppPreferences is non Activity class then just pass current Activity context for separating SharedPreferences related code in separate java class as :

```
public class AppPreferences  
{
    private SharedPreferences settings = null;
    Context context;
    public AppPreferences(Context context){
     this.context=context;
     settings = context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_CREDENTIALS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
//your code here....
```

}

now  pass Activity context using `AppPreferences` constructor as :

```
appPreferences = new AppPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
String email = appPreferences.getPreferenceString("email");
```

Comment: perfect! thanks this worked, thanks for the explanation too. now the only thing is if i force close the app, the email isn't remembered.. do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

Do not extend Activity class in AppPreferences. and remove the `onCreate()` method.

Do like this way.

```
public class AppPreferences extends Activity
{
    private SharedPreferences settings = null;
    AppPreferences(Context context) {
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_CREDENTIALS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    ...//Rest of your code.

}
```

In Login activity.

```
appPreferences = new AppPreferences(this);
```

Comment: your solution works too, though I don't know if that extend has to be there if I only use the preferences