# SharedPreferences doesn't save on force close app

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

I have a login form with a checkbox to let the app remember the email in `LoginActivity`. If I press the Log in button the email should be stored in `SharedPreferences` using the class `AppPreferences`.

The app remembers the email if I return to home screen by pressing home button and by pressing back.

But if I force close the app shows the default value as defined in the `Preferencemanager.getString("value", "default_value");` method.

I have tried a lot of things people suggested on SO, but unfortunately none of the solutions worked. I even tried to solve it by putting all the `SharedPreferences` code in a separate class (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251942/sharedpreferences-makes-app-force-close)).

Below I put as much code relevant to the question. So both the classes `LoginActivity` and `AppPreferences`. There is no error message given by LogCat.

At both the Samsung devices I9100 and P3110 with Android 4.2.2 Cyanogenmod 10.1 and several different emulators this problem occurs. (I read some Samsung S devices with HoneyComb could't save SharedPreferences properly?)

---

**EDIT:**
As I forgot to mention, the project is targeted to API 17 and the minSdkVersion = 11. I only save credentials on click of Log in button.
**EDIT 2:** This problem also occurs if phone reboots

---

the `LoginActivity` class:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String PREF_REMEMBER_EMAIL = "LoginCredentialsRememberEmail";
    private static final String PREF_EMAIL = "LoginCredentialsEmail";

    private String mEmail;

    private EditText mEmailView;
    private CheckBox cbRememberEmail;   

    private AppPreferences appPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(LoginActivity.this);

        loadUserCredentials();
    }
    @Override
  protected void onResume() {       
        super.onResume();
        loadUserCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        loadUserCredentials();
    }

    private void loadUserCredentials() {
        String rememberEmail = appPreferences.getPreferenceString(PREF_REMEMBER_EMAIL);
        String email = appPreferences.getPreferenceString(PREF_EMAIL);
        mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mEmailView.setText((rememberEmail == "1") ? email : "");
        cbRememberEmail = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail);
        cbRememberEmail.setChecked(rememberEmail == "1" ? true : false);
        mEmail = mPassword = "";
    }
    private void saveUserCredentials() {        
        try {
        String rememberemail = (((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail)).isChecked()) ? "1" : "0";
        appPreferences.setPreferenceString(PREF_REMEMBER_EMAIL, rememberemail);
        String email = (rememberemail == "1") ? mEmail : "";
        appPreferences.setPreferenceString(PREF_EMAIL, email);
    }



    public void cbRememberEmailClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail)).isChecked();
        if (checked) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.remember_email_notification_title).setMessage(R.string.remember_email_notification_message).setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail)).setChecked(true);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail)).setChecked(false);
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

The `AppPreferences` class:

```
public class AppPreferences {
    Context context;

    private SharedPreferences settings = null;

    private static String LOGIN_CREDENTIALS = "com.example.login.credentials";
    private static String DEFAULT_STRING = "";

    public AppPreferences(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    private String getKey(String key) {
        return LOGIN_CREDENTIALS + "." + key;
    }

    public String getPreferenceString(String key) {
        return settings.getString(getKey(key), DEFAULT_STRING);
    }
    public void setPreferenceString(String key, String value) throws Exception {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(getKey(key), (String) value);
        editor.commit();
    }
// ...
}
```

Any help is really appreciated, I'm stuck at this for days and it's really frustrating now.

Thanks in advance.

Dediqated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it by changing the field `rememberEmail` to a `Boolean` instead of a string containing a `1` or `0`. I dont know why this didn't work but I'm happier about the fact that after 11 days of frustration this is no issue anymore.

Also did I delete all the preference files in folder `/data/data/com.example/shared_prefs/`

changed code in `LoginActivity`

```
// ....
private void loadUserCredentials() {
    Boolean rememberEmail = appPreferences.getPreferenceBoolean(PREF_REMEMBER_EMAIL);
    String email = appPreferences.getPreferenceString(PREF_EMAIL);
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setText(rememberEmail ? email : "");
    cbRememberEmail = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail);
    cbRememberEmail.setChecked(rememberEmail);
}
private void saveUserCredentials() {        
    try {
    Boolean rememberEmail = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRememberEmail)).isChecked();
    appPreferences.setPreferenceBoolean(PREF_REMEMBER_EMAIL, rememberEmail);
    String email = (rememberEmail) ? mEmail : "";
    appPreferences.setPreferenceString(PREF_EMAIL, email);
}
// ....
```

and in `AppPreferences`

```
// ....
private String getKey(String key) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();
    return LOGIN_CREDENTIALS + "." + key;
}
// newly added methods below
public String getPreferenceBoolean(String key) {
    return settings.getBoolean(getKey(key), DEFAULT_BOOLEAN);
}
public void setPreferenceBoolean(String key, Boolean value) throws Exception {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getKey(key), (Boolean) value);
    editor.commit();
}
// ....
```

I hope you won't make the same mistake as I did ;)

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the code that calls `saveUserCredentials`. You should call it in `onPause`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveUserCredentials();
}
```

If you call it in one of the later lifecycle methods (such as `onDestroy`), it won't be called if the app is force-closed while in the background. (You can defer this to `onStop` if you are targeting only Honeycomb and later.)

Comment: I might be wrong but if you force close the app the onPause or OnDestory wouldn't execute would it as it completely kills the process and any code execution is not done

Comment: @Boardy - If you force-close a foreground app, then there isn't much that you can do to guarantee that data are saved. (You can force-close a foreground app using adb, but it's hard to see how you can do it on the device itself.) If the activity is not in the foreground, then it's `onPause` method will have been called (and the call completed). It's the `onStop` (pre-Honeycomb) and `onDestroy` method calls that are skipped with a force close.

Comment: thanks for your input, but as I mentioned I only save email if Log in button is clicked. I'm sorry I forgot `saveUserCredentials`, this method is called in `cbRememberEmailClick`. Target is API 17 (Honeycomb) and minSdkVersion = 11

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you, putting the save method into the onDestroy method

Comment: `onDestroy` will not be called when a background app is force-closed.

Comment: I only want to save credentials on Login button click

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `saveUserCredentials();` when ever checkbox is checked,This should work perfectly.Also try to initialise preference obj on start of application

Comment: I call `saveUserCredentials()` whenever the login button is clicked, seems more logic to me. However if i force close the app or restart the device nothing is saved..